# Enhancements Tab on Windows 11

Tags: windows, audio, drivers, sound-card

I am having issues on my Lenovo ThinkPad E490 laptop running Windows 11. Trying to plug a set of plug and play headphones via the 3.5 mm jack the sound comes out of them but not at the expected quality - instead, it's quite flat.

I tried to do what I usually do: Go to Settings -> System -> Sound -> More Sound Settings -> select my device -> Properties and add enhancements via the Enhancements tab in the window that shows up. Alas, in this case this doesn't seem to be possible - instead, I am greeted with the following:

[image: Headphones Properties]

I am now lost on how to improve the sound of the pair of headphones. I have the following information in my Device Manager:

[image: Device Manager - Audio inputs and outputs]

[image: Device Manager - Sound, video and game controllers]

Judging by that, I have a Synaptics audio driver. I tried uninstalling it multiple times, restarting the PC and letting the driver reinstall itself. I also tried downloading drivers from the manufacturer's website but this was of no help either.

Is there a way to get the Enhancements tab on the Headphones Properties tab or should I rely on third-party software?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to resolve this via the instructions provided in [this topic](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/hvvbdp/audio_enhancement_tab_missing_software_or/) on Reddit. The following is a paraphrased version of the resolution found in the topic above:

1. Open registry (using `regedit`)
2. Go to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Render`
3. Select the "Properties" keys of each renderer listed (long hash values, e.g. `{992179e6-a1e9-4398-9f9f-dfd08aa60971}`)
4. Look through the values and search for the name of the desired audio output, e.g. "INTELAUDIO", the manufacturer or model of your device, etc.
5. If you found the right renderer which contains the strings from your desired audio output, add a new key called `FxProperties` if it doesn't already exist
6. If there is a prompt that you don't have enough permissions, apply the following to the "Renderer" key: [External article - How To Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/262464/how-to-gain-full-permissions-to-edit-protected-registry-keys/)
7. Inside the `FxProperties` key, add the following entries of type "String":

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| {d04e05a6-594b-4fb6-a80d-01af5eed7d1d},1 | {62dc1a93-ae24-464c-a43e-452f824c4250} |
| {d04e05a6-594b-4fb6-a80d-01af5eed7d1d},2 | {637c490d-eee3-4c0a-973f-371958802da2} |
| {d04e05a6-594b-4fb6-a80d-01af5eed7d1d},3 | {5860E1C5-F95C-4a7a-8EC8-8AEF24F379A1} |

8. Restart your computer
9. Start `regedit` again and see if the keys from above are still there. If not, try adding them and restart again. Try adding the keys, go to the sound properties and if the enhancement tab is there, select a feature like "Loudness Equalization" and then see if the registry entries are there after a restart.
10. If the keys are there, the "Enhancement" tab and "Loudness Equalization" should be back again and working!

Comment: This is a crazy hackfix, and I really did not want to even try it, but after being unable to find any better solution, I grew desperate enough to try it and I can attest, it actually works!
(But then again: Why is this like this? Is it Realtek dropping the ball? I got the issue on my Zenbook with Realtek drivers in Windows 10 btw.)

Comment: Update: It did add the tab, but its utterly useless to help me fix my problem with insufficient volume. The "Loudness Equalizer" looks like its busted. Maybe these are the wrong "values" after all?

Comment: Just a thanks for this post, even though it was not what I was looking for.  I've been looking to disable a *specific* "enhancement" added by my sound drivers without disabling all enhancements.  This was the first post I could find after lots of trawling that actually gave me a clue to where I could see what "enhancements" are registered and mess with them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this utility to enable the "Enhancements" tab on the selected audio device:

https://dinofly.com/files/audio_tweaker_utility.zip

They will show up after applying and rebooting for the device you selected in the GUI.

Loudness Equalization appears to work correctly for me, and if you need an equalizer (since that is no longer in the Enhancements tab), you can use this:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/

The newer Realtek / Nahimic / Realtek Audio Console / Companion App drivers do suck as illustrated in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mt7bLMgdkXk

Answer (score 0):

No Sound Equalization choices on an HP 360 with windows 11.  There is an "enhancements" option in properties, but it is an all on or all off option.  No selectivity at all.  And the speaker volume remains mediocre.  What old Realtek driver has the needed options and works with Windows 11.  Nothing fancy needed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).